# Load More videos script not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video

I tried something but I can see only one video shown on my webpage but when I click to view more nothing happens.

```
<?php
    $dir = "videos/";
    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'mp4'){
                    echo 
                    "<div id='myvido' class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 mbtm15'>
                    <video width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" controls preload=\"auto\">
                    <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/mp4\">
                    <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/ogg\">
                    </video>
                    </div>";
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
?>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

and here is my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myvido video").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myvido video:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myvido video:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myvido video').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

and the css

```
 #myvido video{display: none;}
```

so when i try the above code it's not showing up more videos when i try to click load more it's not working like it should.

Comment: Not sure if more than 1 video is being shown via the `while` loop in your PHP. What does your rendered HTML look like? Any errors in console?

Comment: No console errors....